# Using JQuery to set CSS Keyframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to determine the height of a `div` which is dynamic depending on the size of the text. I was trying to set this dynamically within the CSS as my original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150538/defining-a-height-in-css-for-animation-keyframe-within-itself?noredirect=1#comment37269329_24150538.

I have now seem that there is a JQuery that may enable you to do so at https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes. So I've followed their example and removed the `keyframe` in my `CSS` file and included it in the script as in the below code fragment:

```
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/pathToFile/jquery.keyframes.min.js"></script>

    <div id="test"> hello</div>

<script>
var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();

$.keyframe.define([{
    name: 'myfirst',
       '0%':   {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px},
       '50%':  {top:100%;  left:0px},
       '100%': {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px}
}]);

$(selector).playKeyframe({
name: 'myfirst', // name of the keyframe you want to bind to the selected element
duration: 90, // [optional, default: 0, in ms] how long you want it to last in     milliseconds
timingFunction: 'linear', // [optional, default: ease] specifies the speed curve of the animation
delay: 0, //[optional, default: 0, in ms]  how long you want to wait before the animation starts in milliseconds, default value is 0
repeat: 'infinite', //[optional, default:1]  how many times you want the animation to repeat, default value is 1
direction: 'alternate', //[optional, default: 'normal']  which direction you want the frames to flow, default value is normal
fillMode: 'running', //[optional, default: 'forward']  how to apply the styles outside the animation time, default value is forwards
complete: function(){} //[optional]  Function fired after the animation is complete. If repeat is infinite, the function will be fired every time the animation is restarted.
});


</script>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
#test{
height: auto;
width:  100%;

position: relative;
}
```

I would like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: The error that you receive is normally because there's some hidden character around that messes things up for you. Can you detect it with your editor? Notepad++ (which is my favourite editor) has such function.

Comment: @entiendoNull, That is the only error it's picking up

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The SyntaxError is being caused by your semicolon-delimited javascript objects here:

```
'0%':   {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px},
'50%':  {top:100%;  left:0px},
'100%': {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px}
```

Replace your semicolons with commas inside the objects:

```
'0%':   {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1, left:0},
'50%':  {top:"100%",  left:0},
'100%': {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1, left:0}
```

That will fix the syntax error.

EDIT: In addition, your values for `left` need to be changed from `0px` to `0` or `"0px"`, as `0px` by itself is not valid syntax.

EDIT 2: I played around a bit with this http://jsfiddle.net/7P9yY/2/ and got it to work close to what I believe you're asking.

The keyframe is defined as:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
    name: 'myfirst',
    '0%':   {top:"0px"},
    '50%': {top:$("#testcontainer").innerHeight() + "px"},
    '100%': {top:"0px"}
}]);
```

This keyframe defines a motion starting at the top of the page (you can change this to be the top of the div if you need), down to the bottom, and back up to the top. Fire the animation with:

```
$("#test").playKeyframe({
    name: 'myfirst',
    duration: 2000
});
```

HTML (example):

```
<div id="testcontainer">
    <div id="test">hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS (example):

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
}

#testcontainer {
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Hopefully that helps a little bit.

Comment: I changed these to commas and the error has changed to caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Edited my answer, try that.

Comment: If you're using chrome, you can open up the console (Ctrl-Shift-J) and be able to locate where these syntax issues are occurring, if there are more.

Comment: Hi I now get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , ". That's all chrome is showing me

Comment: Forgot quotes around `100%`

Comment: ok I'm getting no errors now. But instead of expecting the text to scroll to the bottom then back to the top. It comes on the display then disappears and repeats that.

Comment: Thanks I'm using the long version also and I'm just getting a blink still. I've edited my orginal answer with that code. Using the normal CSS animation I was getting the right behavior, but I had to hard code some of the keyframe values, which I thought this would have avoided.

Comment: I've edited it again, I think that might be what you're asking for?

Comment: Thanks it seems to be doing what I want. I've put my script at the end just before my closing <body> tag do you I think I need to move it. As on my system it does not do anything yet?

Comment: Your script is fine where it is, have you added the css styling from the jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes I had similar css to the one in JSFiddle : see edit in original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55403/discussion-between-nile-and-user94628).

Answer (score 5):

I managed to achieve activating a keyframe by creating a class with the name of the keyframe defined

```
.add_keyframe{
  animation: shrink 5s
}
```

and then add this using jquery

```
$('#whatever').addClass('add_keyframe');
```

Once the class is added your keyframe should run.

Comment: If you add class for keyframe, you cannot stop animation using $('#whatever').stop().

Comment: then you can remove the class