# CSS in style tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to ask if there's a way to put some css code in < style>< /style> tags using jQuery. I need this particularly for putting a @keyframes which shouldn't be added to an element but in the < style>< /style> tag.

Comment: Of course you can. $('style').html(your_styles_here);

Comment: DI you try anything?

Comment: @JaysonBuquia wouldn't it be $('.class').css('ATTR', 'VALUE'); ?

Comment: @Top Questions, OP asks to add css code inside the style `tag`, which is different from adding inline styles.

Comment: @JaysonBuquia Oh now I see...

Comment: Wherever possible I always write my `<style>` elements server side for complex things like keyframes, then just use jQuery to add or remove class attributes, which then in turn use those animation keyframes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this simple example where you can turn the text color from red to blue.

You simply use the selector to grab the element you wish to modify with css.

```js
$("button").click(function()
{
    $("span").css("color","blue");
});
```

```css
span
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span> a simple test </span>
    <button> click me </button>
</div>
```

I think for keyframes you could use the following:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
    name: 'myfirst',
       '0%':   {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px},
       '50%':  {top:100%,  left:0px},
       '100%': {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px}
}]);
```

> This is based off the following answer from a similar question on SO 
>   [Using JQuery to set CSS Keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152925/using-jquery-to-set-css-keyframe)
>
> Which uses this JQuery package for accomplishing the question 
>   https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes