# How to create marquee infinite loop of logos slider with css only

Tags: html, css

Right now my code makes the logos animate from right to left and once it hits the end, it restarts. How can I make it continue in a loop so that the first logo follows the last one when a new cycle starts?

EDIT:
I rather not use extra js libraries, so if there is a simple way of doing this with jquery that would be much better

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}
.marquee div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
    <img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that thread uses libraries and I want to just have a quick simple jquery code that does this

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm refer to this link it may help you.

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) check this

Comment: @ParthPatel I'm pretty sure they are using a library. --vicmathur that almost it, except they use a huge image with the logos side by side, but I want to be able to easily add new logos into the code rather than edit the image over and over each time

Comment: @BragDeal couldn't you use a similar solution to the one in @Vicmathur 's link? Just make an outer-container (with `overflow-x:hidden` ) and then animate an inner-container (containing all of your logos) within it.

Comment: @BrianD I tried what you recommended but I can't get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/gkpnx34v/

Comment: @BragDeal http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/jc7F3/285/ try this one. You can set properties like duplicated: true, gap: 00, direction: 'left', pauseOnHover: true.Search for jQuery marquee.

Comment: @ParthPatel it's closer to what I need yes. Is there a way to get the first logo to tail the last one as soon as the last logo appears rather than wait til it gets to the end and then the cycle restarts? http://jsfiddle.net/jc7F3/1462/

Comment: @BragDeal I have posted the solution as you need with the changes to make it continuous.Vote up if it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
  <div class='marquee'>
       .... 
       images
       ....
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.marquee').marquee({
        duration: 5000,
         duplicated: true,
         gap: 00, 
         direction: 'left',
         pauseOnHover: true
    });
});
```

This is what i have done to make it run using JQuery Marquee.

External links:

1. [jquery.pause.js](https://rawgithub.com/tobia/Pause/master/jquery.pause.js)
2. [jquery.marquee.min.js](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js)

Also you can follow this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parth7676/m6jx1qb6/)

Comment: This work yes, I wish there was a way to do this without the extra libraries but whatever it works. Is there a way to have the animation start with the logos already on the screen and then they scroll? right now it starts with nothing and then it slides from the right side

Comment: @BragDeal Yes it is possible to give animation.Just go through this repo https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee . You will find what you want

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? It uses jQuery, which the OP specified CSS only.

Answer (score 6):

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gkpnx34v/2/ --- took a little tinkering, but that should give you the idea.

```css
.tech-slideshow {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size:0; /* THIS IS A HACK TO REMOVE THE "WHITESPACE" BETWEEN IMAGES.
                  YOU COULD ALSO PUT ALL OF THE IMAGES ON THE SAME LINE
                  (eg: <img src=""><img src=""><img src=""> 
                  with no spaces or line-breaks),
                  BUT THAT MAKES THE CODE LESS READABLE SO I'M DOING THIS
                  FOR THE SAKE OF CREATING THIS EXAMPLE FOR YOU */
}

.mover-1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: max-content;
  
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  animation: moveSlideshow 5s linear infinite;
}

.mover-1 img {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100px;
  margin:0;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-500px);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-slideshow">
  <div class="mover-1">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/150">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">

    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/150">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">

    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/150">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Set your `.mover-1` container's width to `max-content` (to auto-size to whatever width is necessary). You could also set it to an arbitrary (huge) width just so you won't have to worry about having logos roll over to the next line.

Then set some styles on your images so they'll line up nicely.

Finally, set the moveSlideshow translateX distance to THE EXACT WIDTH OF *ONE* SET OF LOGOS.

The point is, you want to have 2 sets of logos -- the initial set and then a duplicate that you roll into view. Set your animation to move exactly the width of 1 set and it should loop smoothly.

Just for posterity (and because it's REALLY easy to copy and paste code and doesn't take any extra bandwidth to render) I actually added a 3rd set of logos just to make sure my block of logos was wide enough to never have a gap on wide screens.

P.S. The difference in heights I set on the kitten images (some of them being 150px tall instead of 100px) has nothing to do with the functionality; I just wanted to make sure that you can tell when the animation loops.

P.P.S. Rather than a) manually calculating the total width of the logos or b) adding redundant blocks of logos, you could easily use jQuery to find the width of that `.mover-1` container (`$('.mover-1')[0].width()`) and [set your keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152925/using-jquery-to-set-css-keyframe) to move that distance. Then make an array of the images (`$('.mover-1 img')`), then append/prepend them to the original set.

This code (untested) should get you close:

```
var logos = $('mover-1 img');
$('.mover-1').append(logos).append(logos);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! There is a problem though, something isn't working properly.  https://jsfiddle.net/gkpnx34v/4/ I changed it so you can see the pattern of the animation with colours, you can see that it's not smooth. You can't even see the first green background logo

Comment: You can't see the green background logo because you're only supposed to see the first set of logos (starting with the blue). Once it rolls over to the point that the red is where the blue started, the animation loops back to the beginning. The logos past the red (all the way through the green) are just there in case you're on a SUUUUUPER wide monitor so that you never end up with a blank space between the logos.

Comment: The animation is not smooth, on the other hand, because you're using software rendering to process the animation and it tends to get bogged down. If you want nice smooth animations, you want to use the CSS `transform` attribute `translate3d()` even when you're only working with 2D. `translate3d()` allows you to set 3 different values (x,y,z) and it indicates to the browser to use "hardware rendering" meaning it'll engage the graphics card if you have one. Try running it from your computer instead of jsfiddle too. More here: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm

Comment: I love you so much

Answer (score 0):

I know the question says CSS only, but I find all attempts using only keyframes and HTML leads to unwanted spacing between the logo, overlapping logos, parallax effects, etc.

For those willing to use some JavaScript the following works for me:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="hold_logos"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

#hold_logos {
  height: 200px;
  background: #218c74;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(1400px);
   }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-200px);
   }
}
```

**JS**:

```
images = ["https://www.strunkmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/bigstock-221516158.jpg", "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=360/uploads/users/2273/posts/32751/image/TwoPeaks-Logo.jpg", "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20210711/original/pngtree-colorful-nature-logo-png-image_6511888.jpg", "https://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/symbol-logo-example.jpg", "https://cdn.thebrandingjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/chanel_logo_the_branding_journal.jpg"];
const number_of_logos = 5;
const spacing = (window.innerWidth / number_of_logos)*10;
const duration = (number_of_logos*spacing);
var int_cnt = -1;
var marquee = document.getElementById("hold_logos");
partner_interval = setInterval(function() {
    int_cnt++;
    if(int_cnt < number_of_logos) {
           const img = document.createElement("img");
           img.className = "logo";
           img.src = images[int_cnt];
           marquee.append(img);
    }
}, spacing/1.4);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(partner_interval);
}, duration);
```

**Result**:

[image]

The result is smoother than what the GIF shows since it's still using keyframes.

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/cybertime/pen/MWXjyaw).